# Why will mount sometimes refuse to remount,rw?

Tags: linux, mount

I have a Raspberrypi 4 with a custom Yocto image and a read only root filesystem. As part of the setup I'd like to do:

```
#/bin/sh

mount -o remount,rw /

timedatectl set-timezone $1
sync

mount -o remount,ro /
```

I have tried adding syncs here and there and even adding sleeps but sometimes it's like the mount command just gives up and I get something like:

```
root@raspberrypi4:~# for tz in $(timedatectl list-timezones | head); do /var/tz.sh $tz; done
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
```

Other times everything works great.

Also, I can always just type the commands on the command line:

```
root@raspberrypi4:~# mount -o remount,rw /
root@raspberrypi4:~# timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Accra
root@raspberrypi4:~# mount -o remount,ro /
```

never fails.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: You  are missing a trailing `/` on the mount command in your shell script.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. That was a copy paste error though, the real script actually has it.

Comment: Do you see similar behavior with this command? `mount -o remount,rw /;timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Accra;mount -o remount,ro /` (i.e., run the 3 commands on one command line separated by semicolons)

Comment: @AndyDalton Yes, I have tried that. And also tired replacing `;` with `&` and one version where I added a trap and tried to `remount,ro` on exit, hup and sigint.

Comment: And it worked when you tried that? To be clear, my suggestion was to try that on the command line, not in your script.

Comment: It works from the command line. And if I get my script into the limbo state of refusing to remount rw and then try with that command line, it also works.